# Texture ASCollectionDataSourceInterop + Swift

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

Trying to use `ASCollectionDataSourceInterop` to combine `UICollectionViewCell` and `ASCellNode` in one data source as it is described here

> http://texturegroup.org/docs/uicollectionviewinterop.html

However I run into issue here, because

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: ASCollectionView, nodeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ASCellNode {
        return nil
}
```

Doesnt work in swift, maybe there is a way to workaround in swift

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath: called?

Comment: yes, just no way of returning null in swift

Comment: @Andeius, can u share simple example?

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius I may be misunderstanding your question, but why would you ever return `nil` for `nodeForItemAtIndexPath`? Even with the standard `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, they don't allow for nil to be returned.

We use Texture (AsyncDisplayKit) extensively in our project (100% swift) and have not had any swift related issues or constraints.

Comment: @StephenSilber it's because you haven't tried interop :) Facing the same issue as Andrius right now

Comment: You can even check out the documentation - there is no Swift version for the code example here: https://texturegroup.org/docs/uicollectionviewinterop.html

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: just make the return type an implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
func collectionNode(_ collectionNode: ASCollectionNode,
                    nodeBlockForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ASCellNodeBlock! {
    return optionalNodeBlock
}
```

The compiler does warn you about the type mismatch, but everything works well